# Symfony show profiler bar only for administrator

Tags: php, symfony

I use symfony and I want profiler show only to admins

```
access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
```

Now, profiler show to all users

Comment: May I ask why? The bar is only shown in development mode so it really should not matter.  It won't show in production at all and you probably don't really want it to.  Even for admin types.  The bar itself is basically generated via javascript.  The _profiler and _wdt routes are used by javascript to download the information the bar needs.  I suppose you could intercept these with a request listener and then do something based on roles.  But I don't know of any examples.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Limiting the access through the `security.yaml` might not be enough

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should NOT use profiler in production. As the Symfony documentation says:

> The profiler is a powerful **development tool** that gives detailed information about the execution of any request. **Never** enable the profiler in production environments as it will lead to major security vulnerabilities in your project.

Install it only in development mode:

`composer require --dev symfony/profiler-pack`

Returning to the problem: I think adding profiler pattern to `access_control` may work:

```yaml
access_control:
    - { path: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```